# How to add a header to VBA outside excel

Tags: vba

I have this code working OK with a multi-column listbox
How can I add a header to each column?

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Add multiple Columns to a listbox
ListBox1.Clear 'Make sure the Listbox is empty
ListBox1.ColumnCount = 3 'Set the column Amount
'Fill the Listbox
ListBox1.AddItem "Row Number 1" 'Additem creates a new row
ListBox1.List(0, 1) = "Column Number 2" 'List(x,y) X is the row number, Y the column number
ListBox1.List(0, 2) = "Column Number 3"
ListBox1.List(0, 3) = "Column Number 4"
ListBox1.AddItem "Row Number 2"
ListBox1.List(1, 1) = "Column Number 2"
ListBox1.List(1, 2) = "Column Number 3"
ListBox1.List(1, 3) = "Column Number 4"
ListBox1.AddItem "Row Number 3"
ListBox1.List(2, 1) = "Column Number 2"
ListBox1.List(2, 2) = "Column Number 3"
ListBox1.List(2, 3) = "Column Number 4"

End Sub
```

[See the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TP6rb.png)

Comment: To do this you will need to load the list from a hidden worksheet.

Comment: My comment above concerns Excel-VBA. If you're in Access=VBA or Word-VBA it might be feasible, idk.

Comment: AFAIK it's possible only by setting the `RowSource` property to Excel Range. Otherwise, you can use `ListView` instead

Comment: This VB application is running outside Excel or Access. I am searching to see if a header to each column is possible

Comment: Then where is it running? It should be possible with some complicated WinAPI calls, but that seems like too much trouble. You can use more appropriate control like ListView instead https://markdagosta.com/2011/02/16/listview-control/